# Group tables by schema in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

In Visual Studio's Server Explorer window there's a very nice feature that lets you see the DB objects grouped by schema:

It turns this object tree:

> Data Connections -> *MyServer* -> Tables -> *MyTable* (*MySchema*)

Into this one:

> Data Connections -> *MyServer* -> Schemas -> *MySchema* -> *MyTable*

[image: VS feature]

---

I've been looking for this particular feature in SSMS but was unable to find it.

- Does it exist?
- If not, is there a plugin which would provide this feature?
- Or perhaps is there a plugin which would help ease navigation in DBs which have *lots* of objects?

Please note I'm aware of SSMS object filters. It's better than nothing but not sufficient, as I'm often accessing objects from multiple schemas at once.

Comment: Did you mean "**in** SSMS" in the title of the question? (As opposed to "**is** SSMS")

Comment: @ispiro oops, thanks for spotting this typo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want a free tool, [SSMS Schema Folders](https://github.com/nicholas-ross/SSMS-Schema-Folders/releases) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/nicholas-ross/SSMS-Schema-Folders)) is your solution. It does the job beautifully.

[image: Folder per each schema]

Comment: That's the solution! Thanks :) It breaks the "go to definition" feature of another extension I use though, but at least the tree is not a huge mess anymore.

Comment: That CodePlex reference redirets to GitHub now: https://github.com/nicholas-ross/SSMS-Schema-Folders/issues.  Looks like a cool add in that I might try one day.

Comment: I wish all the tables, views, sprocs etc could be viewed under a single schema node: still have to travel up and down the tree to see all the related stuff, instead of _ok, I'm working on payroll now, so the payroll node has all my tables, views, sprocs, etc_

Comment: INFO: Alas, SSMS Schema Folders is extremely slow when you have serveral thousands of views. For around 25k views, it takes 5 or more minutes for it to sort them by schema.

Answer (score 3):

I love the idea of grouping by schema.

[SQL Treeo SSMS Addin](https://www.sqltreeo.com/sqltreeo-ssms-add-in) is an inexpensive tool that allows you to create your own table structure in the Object Explorer.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very nice. I'll give it a try.

Comment: interesting one, just fixed the URL to it

Answer (score 1):

You can try as follows in SSMS:
Tables > Filter > Filter Settings

There you are able to filter by schema...

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically pointed out in my answer that I'm already aware about filters. This is not the feature I'm looking for.

Comment: nevertheless useful for others who don't know about filters at all