# Group tables by schema in ADS

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, ssms, ssms-2017, azure-data-studio

In Visual Studio's Server Explorer window there's a very nice feature that lets you see the DB objects grouped by schema:

It turns this object tree:

> Data Connections -> MyServer -> MySchema.MyTable

Into this one:

> Data Connections -> MyServer -> Schemas -> MySchema -> MyTable

I've been looking for this particular feature in ADS but was unable to find it.

Does it exist?
If not, is there a plugin which would provide this feature?
Or perhaps is there a plugin which would help ease navigation in DBs which have lots of objects?

Something like this 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Right click on a Database -> "Enable Group by Schema"

[image]

Then you will see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No matter Visual Studio's Server Explorer、SSMS or other tools, the all let our see the DB objects grouped by schema:

> Data Connections -> MyServer -> MySchema.MyTable

If these tools don't have the feature you want, I think ADS also doesn't.

Hope this helps.

Comment: SSMS has this feature but i dont find it in ADS

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425888/group-tables-by-schema-in-ssms