# Group tables by schema in vscode-extension mssql

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

This question is similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425888/group-tables-by-schema-in-ssms), but for vscode rather than SSMS.

In Vscode a popular extension for connecting to SQL servers is the [mssql](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mssql) extension. But in the best SQL server fashion, tables are not grouped by schema. Is there a viable method (either through settings, existing extensions or extending the extension oneself) to group tables by schema?

For example in the below image the 3 tables would be grouped under the "extract" schema, so the folder structure would be "db/tables/{schemaname}/{tablename}" (or alternatively "db/schemma/{schemaname}/{tablename}" as in DBeaver)

[image: vscode-db-image]

Comment: This seem like something you should be asking as a [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mssql/issues/new) on the extension's [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mssql).

Comment: Indeed, I will. If no one comes with a "you can just do this". To avoid double posting I'll let this question sit for a day or 2 first.

Comment: A quick scan of the settings for the MSSQL extension says it isn't there. Considering it's not native to SSMS either, and you have to use an add-on to do it, I would be surprised it it is native to the MSSQL extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Data Studio 1.42 supports **Group By Schema** feature.

> [Announcing the Release of Azure Data Studio 1.42 by Erin Stellato](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/announcing-the-release-of-azure-data-studio-1-42/ba-p/3775318)
>
> One of the original feature requests for Azure Data Studio was the ability to view objects by schema in Object Explorer (OE).  Finally, that functionality is available in this release for the MSSQL provider:
>
> [image]
>
> The default behavior shows the objects grouped by type (Tables, Views, etc.) and can be quickly toggled by clicking the branching icon in the Servers View. The configuration persists through restarts of Azure Data Studio, and it applies across all MSSQL connections; it is not selective to instance or database.